# after entering the value in the textbox if I hit enter, should see a new chip with the entered value in it

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- when I click textbox text a menu opens, in that textbox I need to enter some value in the textbox.
- after entering the value in the textbox if I hit enter, I should see a new chip with the entered value in it.
- so I thought I will create an Onchange event and pass the values to the chip component
- but the values are not getting passed.
- I think I need to pass values an object to that array.

`chipData.push(handleTextBox);
  console.log("handleTextBox after push chipData--->", chipData);`

- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet  and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-99sf8

```or-tag-here
demo.js

 const [chipData, setChipData] = React.useState([
    { key: 0, label: "Angular" },
    { key: 1, label: "jQuery" },
    { key: 2, label: "Polymer" },
    { key: 3, label: "React" },
    { key: 4, label: "Vue.js" }
  ]);

  const [hideChip, setHideChip] = React.useState([false]);

  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl({ type: "icon", target: event.currentTarget });
  };

  const handleClickFilter = event => {
    setAnchorEl({ type: "textbox", target: event.currentTarget });
  };

  const handleTextBox = event => {
    console.log("handleTextBox event--->", event);
    console.log("handleTextBox event.target.value--->", event.target.value);
  };

  console.log("handleTextBox handleTextBox--->", handleTextBox);
  console.log("handleTextBox chipData--->", chipData);

  chipData.push(handleTextBox);
  console.log("handleTextBox after push chipData--->", chipData);

 <Menu
              id="simple-menu"
              anchorEl={
                anchorEl && anchorEl.type === "textbox" && anchorEl.target
              }
              open={Boolean(anchorEl && anchorEl.type === "textbox")}
              onClose={handleClose}
            >
              <MenuItem>
                <form
                  className={classes.container}
                  noValidate
                  autoComplete="off"
                >
                  <TextField
                    id="standard-name"
                    label="Name"
                    className={classes.textField}
                    onChange={handleTextBox}
                    // value={values.name}
                    // onChange={handleChange('name')}
                    margin="normal"
                  />
                </form>
              </MenuItem>
            </Menu>

            <Paper className={classes.root}>
              {chipData.map(data => {
                let icon;
                console.log("setHideChip--->", setHideChip);

                if (data.label === "React") {
                  icon = <TagFacesIcon />;
                }

                return (
                  <Chip
                    key={data.key}
                    icon={icon}
                    label={data.label}
                    onDelete={handleDelete(data)}
                    className={classes.chip}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </Paper>
```

Comment: have you checked the browser developer tools console for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code .

```
<TextField
      fullWidth={true}
        id="standard-name"
        label="Tags"
        className={classes.textField}
        onChange={handleChange('tag')}
        onKeyDown={(e) => pushToarray(e)}
        margin="dense"
      />
```

on entering you should see tag being added

```
 function pushToarray(e){
    if(e.key == 'Enter'){
      e.preventDefault();

    setValues({  tags : [...values.tags ,e.target.value] ,
                  tag : ''})
    }
  }
```

and normal handleChange of text change in the box :

```
 const handleChange = name => event => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
    console.log(values)
  };
```

Initialize state like this I have initialized with empty array you can use keys:

```
const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    tag :'',
    tags: [],
  })
```

here is your handleDelete function to remove chips :

```
function handleDelete(item){
    var rm = values.tags.indexOf(item);
      values.tags.splice( rm, 1)

      setValues( { tags : values.tags})
  }
```

this is how your chip component should be

```
<Paper className={classes.root}>
            {
        values.tags && values.tags.map( (tag ,id) =>(
          <Chip color="default" className={classes.chip} onDelete={() => handleDelete(tag)} key={id} label={tag}/>
        ))
      }
```

Comment: hey I updated your code in sandbox, I am getting empty value in the chip, the chip should generate after I hit enter in the text box with value in it. Can you update the code in sandbox and give comments, so that it will be easy to understand

Comment: I’m out rn. I will update the code once i reach. No issues

Comment: Hey, @tkkk I have used these same examples I have given in answer and updated the sandbox, try putting an item using input. Please accept the answer, if it helped. Also, I haven't written handleDelete.

Comment: sorry i forgot to post the link : https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-gz3t0, Please check and reply if it works.

Comment: hey after I hit enter the popup menu should disappear, and when I hit cross symbol on the chip I am not able to delete that particular chip , you can test your code here https://gz3t0.csb.app

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-wduv0 here is the link to the updated one

Comment: can you test it once again, newly created chips still I am not able to delete...can you click the cross icon in the chip and see

Comment: sorry, I was a little busy today. I have updated the answer for delete function, replace it with your existing handleDelete.

Comment: working example here : https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-059bv

Comment: hey I updated your code with api, but the problem is when I enter dessert name in the textbox and hit nter the chip shows the dessert name, but in the table I should show only that particular row, providing my updated code here https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-o8wb4

Comment: I think i have answered what was there in the question. You are adding more layers to the question.

Comment: hey I accepted your answer, can you please help me with this alone.. ---->  but the problem is when I enter dessert name in the textbox and hit nter the chip shows the dessert name, but in the table I should show only that particular row, providing my updated code here codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-o8wb4